# i am not able to do cursor.pretty() in servlets to print my data via mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

```
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
 DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("mycollection"); whereQuery.put("employee", "bonus");  
 DBCursor cursor =coll.find(whereQuery); 
 cursor.pretty();
```

context  i am not able to do cursor.pretty() as method is not associated with `DBCursor`

I am printing data using

```
 while(cursor.hasNext()) 
{
     out.println(cursor.next(););
    out.println("</br>");
 }
```

please give me  a way for pretty printing in servlets

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the pretty function is only available in the mongo shell. You will have to write a function yourself.

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't find pretty in `DBCursor`.By using [the tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-enable-pretty-print-json-output-gson/) based on Google Gson i found a work around which is mentioned below

```
Document myDoc = collection.find().first();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(myDoc);
System.out.println(json);
```

which will be printed like below and i have mongodb java driver 3.2.1

```
{
  "_id": {
 "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb577"
 },
"student_id": 0,
"type": "exam",
"score": 54.6535436362647
}
```

the below code may

```
DBObject myObj = cursor.hasNext();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(myObj);
out.println(json);
out.println("<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (cursorDoc.hasNext()) {

        System.out.println("Printning value of cursor " +cursorDoc.next());
          if(cursorDoc.hasNext()) {
                DBObject o = cursorDoc.next();   
                String Name= (String) o.get("Name") ; 

                request.setAttribute("shopname",shopname);

                RequestDispatcher dispatcher =request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }
```